# Tuple return type with same length as input tuple, or array if input is an array

Tags: typescript

I want to set the return type of a function to a tuple with the length of the length of an argument array if the length is known at build time. Otherwise the return type should be a boolean array.

The first part is working, however when the length is unknown at build time the type is an empty tuple without any type.

```js
type Tuple<
  T,
  Length extends number,
  Accumulator extends T[] = [],
> = Accumulator["length"] extends Length
  ? Accumulator
  : Tuple<T, Length, [...Accumulator, T]>;

function useHasPermissions<
  const T extends {
    schemaName: string;
    action: string;
  }[],
>(args: { permissions: T }): Tuple<boolean, T["length"]> {
  return [] as any;
}
```

Call with tuple (length known at build time):

```js
// const tup: [boolean, boolean, boolean]
const tup = useHasPermissions({
  permissions: [
    {
      schemaName: "User",
      action: "read",
    },
    {
      schemaName: "User",
      action: "create",
    },
    {
      schemaName: "User",
      action: "update",
    },
  ],
});
```

Call with dynamic array (length unknown at build time):

```js
const arr = useHasPermissions({
  permissions: getAtRuntime(),
});

// Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'.ts(2493)
// Should be: boolean[]
const a = arr[0];
```

Comment: Could you reduce your example? I can reproduce it without the whole object structure; an array of strings is enough. And the fix will likely be similar: some `extends` magic to check the length (I recall doing this before; checking if a tuple is bounded).

Comment: Using this as the return type seems to work: `number extends T["length"] ? boolean[] : Tuple<boolean, T["length"]>` ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLAdKW)). Does that answer your question? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: If your use case is "output array type with same structure as input array type" then you can use a simple mapped type without all the recursion and conditional typing, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKblGm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer, otherwise what's the unmet use case?

Comment: @jcalz Neat! I forgot you could simply use a mapped type over tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an input array type and want to produce an output array type of the same general shape but with different element types, you can simply use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Mapped types automatically produce array types from (generic) array types, and tuple types from tuple types.  For your example it looks like:

```
export function useHasPermissions<
  const T extends {
    schemaName: string;
    action: string;
  }[],
>(args: { permissions: T }): { [I in keyof T]: boolean } {
  return [] as any;
}
```

And then it works as desired:

```
const tup = useHasPermissions({
  permissions: [
    { schemaName: "User", action: "read", },
    { schemaName: "User", action: "create", },
    { schemaName: "User", action: "update", },
  ]
});
// const tup: [boolean, boolean, boolean]

const arr = useHasPermissions({
  permissions:
    getAtRuntime(),
});
// const arr: boolean[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyQZ2AAkBDfABWCgFtN99sV8AeAKDjjR33gBU5QMYCgAm+OAG92HOPjQALYNRIA5EtWAAuWTCiYUAcwDc0jiQyNtPPYZMcAvgG0AugBpWAPgAUJKAfzaEnBgVLT0jAFw-PYAlIFwjgCScPpwANbAAJ4QCFHO2gBGEBAANsAkuPaS0lDAMEhQuC5wZC0omSb2rKxcTPD1YHAAvHiEpBShdAzcXlIcITRTEdqOppKyCkqq6lpwAEQAqoRQe64tFjjae7UkIqdw9u4y63KKymoaV0dU9+ZYl-s0DchPdHmsgq8th9dodjr8LigrkgwCISCCzmCOM5WLETAB6PGcbj9ZErIqlcooM7ksoVanFWkobGsETANAlXzARCoBFwAx1ACCMAASqgsBovHE4AKoFASJlmBDNu8dlZdPoDGc-pYdDYDA8PCZejwWrLhqNiGRKItwjM5sFJramJo1vyYELRShxcBJe5cawCUS+qaoIUGZSXN0gA)